# How do I start a background process in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, background, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having some difficulties to starting a background process in Ruby.

I've this code right now.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -w
require "daemons"
require 'rubygems'

path = "#{File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))}/.."

Daemons.run_proc('stalker',{
  :dir_mode => :normal,
  :dir => "#{path}/tmp/pids",
  :backtrace => true,
  :monitor => false,
  :log_output => true
}) do
  system "stalk #{path}/config/jobs.rb"
end
```

I then start the script using `script/stalker start`.

The problem is that I can't stop it. It saves the wrong PID into the pid file.

Like this:

```
script/stalker start
=> stalker: process with pid **39756** started.

ps aux | grep ruby 
=> linus    **39781**   0,3  1,9  2522752  78864   ??  S     8:39pm   0:10.11 ruby stalk script/../config/jobs.rb
```

Why doesn't the first pid match the one printed using `ps aux | grep ruby`?

I've tried using `exec`, `%x{}` and this one `system` to run the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `run_proc`, the code that you want daemonized should go in the block.  Starting another process with `system` doesn't make sense (It will `fork` the process (giving you yet another pid), and then `exec` your jobs.rb script.  Either move the code from `jobs.rb` into the `run_proc` block, or use [Daemons.run](http://daemons.rubyforge.org/classes/Daemons.html#M000004)